# Twitter Sentiment Analysis

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, sentiment-analysis

I am running:

```
select * 
from table
```

and I am getting this error:

> Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: java.io.StringReader@570e45; line: 1, column: 2]

The tweets are also in a language that I don't know.  Is this necessary to have an extension of `json` in tweets?

Comment: A little more info about the data you are working with would certainly be helpful.

Comment: Sir  I am working on JSON format of twitter data and i am storing it as a text in hdfs. Now When i am loading data it is storing at the location but selecting * from table is not giving any output.

Comment: Your question and the title of your question do not relate to each other

Comment: Sir if you can answer the question please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the configuration file in flume. I too faced the issue and resolved by adding the below properties in twitter.conf.

```
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.maxBatchSize = 50000
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.maxBatchDurationMillis = 100000
```